# Unable to set list of lists as series onto dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with many records. Based on the event (one of my columns) I extract it as a list and manually do list slicing to simulate sliding window of arbitrary size. However, while it applied to first group of my dataframe, it fails to work for the other groups in my dataframe, only giving NaN values. I printed out the values before I try to use .loc to set the series onto my dataframe and the values exist.

1st iteration:

```
        timestamp   event   String pattern
    0   2021-12-18 18:20:25+08:00   w   w
    1   2021-12-18 18:20:27+08:00   w   ww
    2   2021-12-18 18:20:29+08:00   w   www
    3   2021-12-18 18:20:31+08:00   w   wwww
    4   2021-12-18 18:20:33+08:00   w   wwwww
    ... ... ... ...
    1131    2021-12-18 18:58:07+08:00   w   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
    1132    2021-12-18 18:58:09+08:00   w   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
    1133    2021-12-18 18:58:11+08:00   w   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
    1134    2021-12-18 18:58:13+08:00   w   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
    1135    2021-12-18 18:58:15+08:00   w   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

2nd iteration:

```
    timestamp   event   String pattern
1136    2021-12-19 07:20:43+08:00   r   NaN
1137    2021-12-19 07:20:45+08:00   w   NaN
1138    2021-12-19 07:20:47+08:00   w   NaN
1139    2021-12-19 07:20:49+08:00   w   NaN
1140    2021-12-19 07:20:51+08:00   w   NaN
... ... ... ...
1781    2021-12-19 07:42:13+08:00   w   NaN
1782    2021-12-19 07:42:15+08:00   w   NaN
1783    2021-12-19 07:42:17+08:00   w   NaN
1784    2021-12-19 07:42:19+08:00   w   NaN
1785    2021-12-19 07:42:21+08:00   w   NaN
```

code:

```
unique_val = merged.timeframe.unique()

for val in unique_val:
    merged_filtered = merged[merged['timeframe']==val]
    merged_filtered.loc[:, 'String pattern'] = ""

    shift = 30

    events = merged_filtered.event.tolist()
    values = []
    
    #print(events)
    
    for i in range(len(events)):
        #print(str(i))
        if i < shift:
            values.append(events[:i+1])
        else:
            values.append(events[i-shift+1:i+1])
    
    
    #print(values)       
    merged_filtered.loc[:, 'String pattern'] = pd.Series(values).str.join('')
    display(merged_filtered[['timestamp', 'event', 'String pattern']])
```

The above is the code I am using. I get the unique groups (timeframes) in the dataframe, filter it out, and apply the sliding window to each group individually by using tolist() and slicing the list indices based on shift, the supposed window size (inclusive of current record)

merged looks like the following:

```
    timeframe   timestamp   event   confidence  String pattern
0   2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:20:25+08:00   w   2.0 w
1   2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:20:27+08:00   w   2.0 ww
2   2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:20:29+08:00   w   2.0 www
3   2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:20:31+08:00   w   2.0 wwww
4   2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:20:33+08:00   w   2.0 wwwww
... ... ... ... ... ...
1131    2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:58:07+08:00   w   2.0 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
1132    2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:58:09+08:00   w   2.0 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
1133    2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:58:11+08:00   w   2.0 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
1134    2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:58:13+08:00   w   2.0 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
1135    2021-12-18 18:21:25 +0800 to 2021-12-18 18:54:...   2021-12-18 18:58:15+08:00   w   2.0 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

Comment: What does `merged` contain?

Comment: merged is the dataframe. I merged each of the group's dataframes into one large dataframe

Comment: I read online that the filtering I am using ```merged_filtered = merged[merged['timeframe']==val]``` does not mean that a new dataframe is created. ie it is original but just filtered to show a subset. does this mean that everytime i set the values as a series, it is only set to the earlier records so thats why later records show NaN @sotmot?

Comment: i am going to test that out right now

Comment: turns out, it was right! the series is being set on to the original dataframe. Not the filtered subset. meaning that I was replacing the series each time. The solution is to either 1) not reset the values on each iteration of the loop, or 2) when filtering the dataframe, make it a completely separate new dataframe